# Has a finite group, generated by $a,b$ always a relation of the form $1=a b a^{\alpha} b^{\beta}$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Question as stated in the title: Has a finite group, generated by $a,b$ always a relation of the form $1=a b a^{\alpha} b^{\beta}$?

If not, can you give me a counterexample?

Thanks

Comment: If the group is finite, then both $a$ and $b$ have finite order, so you don't even need two copies of each.

Comment: Your'e totally right... I corrected my question. Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you try and find a counterexample yourself?

Comment: There was a sequence of papers by a chap called [Jesse Douglas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesse_Douglas) who wrote down all finite groups $G$ which have this form. The reference is *On finite groups with two independent generators I-IV* (so, four different papers), Proc. Nat, Acad. Sci. USA 37, 1951. Although I cannot come up with a counter-example off the top of my head, my point is that *a counter-example does exist*.

Comment: Ok great! That would have been my next question :)
I think $a=(12)(34)$ $b=(123)$ in $A_4$ do the job.

Comment: Or even $(1,2)$ and $(2,3)$ in $S_3$.

Comment: Your comment above makes sense. What first confused me is that $S_3$ _can_ be generated by $a,b$ with $a^2=b^3=abab=1$ as well as all other groups up to order $15$... Thanks a lot!

Comment: I got $A_5$ with the generators $(123)$ and $(12345)$. In retrospect, this was overkill...

Comment: EDIT: and similar for all the other groups up to order 15

Comment: @Adrian I think you might want to edit your question. You seem to be asking: *Does there exist a two-generated finite group $G$ such that no generating pair $a, b$ admits a relation of the form $aba^{\alpha}b^{\beta}=1$.* I think $A_5$ might be promising, as you have simplicity to play with (so, for example, generators of order two can be hit with simplicity, because you obtain $ab^ia^{-1}=b^j$).

Comment: No, I really meant fixed $a$ and $b$. But as I already said, I initially wasn't aware that it depends on the choice of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: You should record your counterexample as an answer to take this question off the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. A counterexample from Derek Holt is: take $a=(1,2)$ and $b=(2,3)$ in $S_3$. The situation depends on the choice of generators as $a=(1,2)$ and $b=(1,2,3)$ in $S_3$ show.